# Sending e-mails with Spring Email

Tags: java, spring, email

I'm trying to send an e-mail with Spring Email.

My bean:

```
@Bean
public JavaMailSender getJavaMailSender() {
    JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
    mailSender.setHost(„???“);
    mailSender.setPort(587);

    mailSender.setUsername(„???“);
    mailSender.setPassword(„???“);

    Properties props = mailSender.getJavaMailProperties();
    props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.debug", "true");

    return mailSender;
}
```

Send function:

```
public void sendSimpleMessage(String to, String subject, String text) {

    SimpleMailMessage message = new SimpleMailMessage(); 
    message.setTo(to); 
    message.setSubject(subject); 
    message.setText(text);
    emailSender.send(message);
}
```

I'm receiving a positive response, but the e-mail is not delivered.

```
250 OK id=1dHroI-0002US-95
DEBUG SMTP: message successfully delivered to mail server
QUIT
221 smtprelay07.ispgateway.de closing connection
```

Can anyone please tell what could be wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Did you set the FROM in the email? If yes, are you receiving any response from the mail server with any error message?

Comment: I changed the code, adding "message.setFrom(...)". Now it works fine! Thank you very much! Actually I expected that the framework would automatically use the property set via mailSender.setUsername(...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

message.setFrom(...) solved the problem!